# Parameterizing divots in contour integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have recently attempted to pick up complex analysis and have been stuck on this problem for a few days:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

Fortunately, it would seem that this question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646096/calculating-int-0-infty-frac-sin2xx2dx-using-the-residue-theorem).

Unfortunately, I have tried to replicate the steps taken, only to find myself stuck.

In particular, computing the following is where I'm having difficulties:

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \frac{e^{i 2 x}}{x^2} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 \mathrm{d}\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{1+i 2 \epsilon e^{i \phi} + \cdots}{\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}} = 0$$

And in particular, the second integrand. From my understanding, the aforementioned integral is due to a pole at $x=0$ and therefore the need to integrate around it. My understanding of the derivation of it is as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{divot} \mathrm{d}x \frac{e^{i 2 x}}{x^2}
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to0} {\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \mathrm{d}x \frac{e^{i 2 x}}{x^2}}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to0} {\int_{\pi}^0 \mathrm{d}\phi*i\epsilon e^{i \phi}
\frac{e^{2i\epsilon\exp(i\theta)}}{\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}}}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to0} {i\int_{\pi}^0 \mathrm{d}\phi\frac{1+i 2 \epsilon e^{i \phi} + \cdots}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to0} {i\int_{\pi}^0 \mathrm{d}\phi\frac{1}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}+2i+\cdots}\\
&\approx \lim_{\epsilon \to0} {i} \bigg[i\frac{1}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}} + 2i\phi \bigg]_\pi^0\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to0} i \bigg[\frac{2i}{\epsilon} -2\pi i \bigg]
\end{align}$$

But as $\epsilon \to 0$, the result tends to $\infty$. In fact, I've been having similar issues with other integrals where $\epsilon$ appears in the denominator of the limit.

I suspect this is due to a lack of understanding on my end, but amusingly I lack the understanding to see where my reasoning is flawed. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: OK, the solution is a little unclear.  In the solution, the sine term is written as a difference of two exponentials - it is the difference in which the singularity cancels.  Sorry this was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x} dx =  \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin 2u}{2u} d(2u) =\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin 2u}{u} du$$
Apply Integration by parts 
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sin^2x}{x(-1)}\biggr|_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2 \sin x \cos x }{x}\mathrm{d}x =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac {\sin x} x dx =\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

To calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac {\sin x} x dx\hspace{10pt}$follow [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2/8350#8350) it already has 26 answers.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=2\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\pi$$

Comment: I think he performed one iteration of integration by parts.

Comment: @Zachary Sorry, I deleted my comment before seeing yours. Thank you.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you went from $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin 2u}{u} du$ to $\underbrace{\left[\frac{\sin^2 u}{u}\right]_0^\infty}_{=0} +\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2u}{u^2} du$?

Comment: see the edited answer hope it is clear now

Comment: hey, @Narida do you understand the proof or you are still confused?

Comment: your edit has made it much clearer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(2x)}{x^2}dx$$
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(2x)}{x^2}dx$$
$$u=2x\,,dx=\frac{du}{2}$$
$$I=-2\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos(u)}{u^2}du-2\Re\int_{0}^\infty\frac{e^{iu}}{u^2}du$$
then maybe:
$$I(a)=-2\Re\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{iu}e^{-au^2}}{u^2}du$$
so:
$$I'(a)=2\Re\int_0^\infty e^{iu}e^{-au^2}du=2\Re\int_0^\infty e^{-au^2+iu}du$$
$$I'(a)=2\Re\left(e^{-\frac{1}{4a}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\left(\sqrt{a}u-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)^2}du\right)$$
And this can then be solved through manipulation of the error function, although getting back to $I(a)$ and evaluating $\lim_{a\to 0}I(a)$ could be difficult.