# Questions regarding $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> question: $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}dx$ is equal to
>
> (A)$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$
>
> (B)$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x}dx$
>
> (C)$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos^2x}{x^2}dx$
>
> (D)None of the above

I tried splitting the integral as $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos^2x}{x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx-\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos^2x}{x^2}dx$$
But for the first integrand, the function is not defined when $x=0$.
Then I tried using $$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$ but that did not work as well.

Comment: the right answer is only $A$

Comment: That's correct. How did you solve it?

Comment: see here http://hubpages.com/education/How-to-Integrate-sinxx-and-cosxx

Comment: and here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141695/how-to-calculate-the-integral-of-sin2x-x2

Comment: see this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-of-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-xx-right2-mathrm-dx-frac-pi2

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508827