# principal value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus, complex-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I know the answer is $\pi$ there is a proof
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141695/how-to-calculate-the-integral-of-sin2x-x2).
Now looking to my textbook ([textbook image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XAuL.png)) the result should be $0$.
Using the last equation on the right hand page we have:
$$ i\pi(\sin^2(x))'|_{x=0} = 0 $$
and there are no other poles except $0$ so the result should be $0$.

What is the problem? Is the definition for principal value different in the two cases?

Comment: $\sin^2(x) / x^2$ is analytic and integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.. so it is a normal Riemann integral, not a principal value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may observe that, by the Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$, 
$$
\sin x=x+O(x^3)
$$ giving
$$
\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}=1+O(x^2),
$$ on the other hand, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\left|\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\right|\leq \frac1{x^2}
$$ consequently the given integral is convergent:
$$
0<\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\:dx<\infty.
$$
No need to consider a principal value: there is no singularity of $\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

We have

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\:dx=2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\:dx=2\cdot \frac{\pi}2=\pi,
> $$

a proof of the latter integral evaluation may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-of-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-xx-right2-mathrm-dx-frac-pi2).

Comment: Right by what is wrong with the equation in my textbook? It seems to be very general. @Olivier

Comment: @Jack996 I think the problem is that in the book when writing $\frac{f(x)}{(x-x_0)^2}$ it clear that the singularity at $x_0$ **can't** be removed. But in your example $\frac{\sin^2 x}{(x-x_0)^2}=1+O(x^2)$ the singularity has been removed, there is no pole of the integrand anymore... It is not the same situation... Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I see but I didn't quite understand how you proved the integral is convergent. @Olivier

Comment: The given integral is convergent because we may write $\int_{-\infty}^\infty=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}+\int_{-1}^{1}+\int_{1}^{\infty}$. the integral in the middle is convergent since the integrand is *continuous* over $[-1,1]$ (see taylor's expansion of $\sin$), the other two integrals are convergent since each one is $\leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac1{x^2}dx<\infty$ (we have $|\sin^2 x|\leq1$).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x} & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\
\overbrace{\bracks{\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic kx}\,\dd k}}
^{\ds{{\sin\pars{x} \over x}}}\
\overbrace{\bracks{\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{-\ic qx}\,\dd q}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{{\sin\pars{x} \over x}}}
\\[3mm] & =
{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\ \overbrace{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic\pars{k - q}x}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi}}
^{\ds{\delta\pars{k - q}}}\ \,\dd k\,\dd q =
{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\
\overbrace{\int_{-1}^{1}\delta\pars{k - q}\,\dd k}^{\ds{=\ 1}}\
\,\dd q
\\[3mm] & =
{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\dd q = \color{#f00}{\pi}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

That kind of integrals are best managed through integration by parts. We have:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\sin^2 x}{x}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz=\color{red}{\pi}.$$