# Convergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}~\mathrm dx.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Determine whether the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}~\mathrm dx$$ converges.

I know it converges, since in general we can use complex analysis, but I'd like to know if there is a simpler method that doesn't involve complex numbers. But I cannot come up with a function that I could compare the integral with.

Comment: Hint: Split the single integral into two integrals

Comment: @FlybyNight No need to make it red.

Comment: @FlybyNight He probably means to split it over $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Good point.

Comment: "since in general we can use complex analysis": what justification is that ??

Comment: I knew that there are ways to calculate the exact value of this integral (e. g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141695/how-to-calculate-the-integral-of-sin2x-x2) using using methods of complex analysis. I just needed a simplier solution.

Comment: @maq what Yves is hinting at is you can 'compute' something before you know it exists. It just means that you wasted your time. Complex analysis tools work on the assumption that the improper integrals exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:$$x>1\implies0\le\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\le\frac1{x^2}\\0<x<1\implies1\le\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\le\frac1{\cos^2(x)}\le\frac1{\cos^2(1)}$$The second of the two coming from the proof of the derivative of $\sin$ using squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 5):

For $x>1$ $$\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\le \frac{1}{x^2}$$ and  For $x<1$ 
$$ |\sin x|\le |x|\implies \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\le  1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using integration by part $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx=\\
-\frac{1}{x}\sin^2(x) |^b_a-\int_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{x}2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx$$note that $\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{1}{x}\sin^2(x)\to 0$and also $\lim_{x\to \infty}-\frac{1}{x}\sin^2(x)\to 0$ so 
$$-\frac{1}{x}\sin^2(x) |^b_a-\int_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{x}2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx=\\0-(-)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx=\\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}dx=\\\frac{\pi}{2}$$ It is well known $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\bf{Remark}$: let:

$$I(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-tx} dx$$

Note:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-tx}=\frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-tx}(-x)$$

So by differentiation of parameter,we have

$$I'(t)=-\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \sin x dx$$

And through integration by parts twice we have:

$$I'(t)=-\frac{1}{t^2+1}$$

Hence,

$$I(t)=\int -\frac{1}{t^2+1} dt$$

$$I(t)=-\arctan (t) +c$$

when $t \to \infty$, $I(t) \to 0$ so :

$$I(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan t$$

Let $t \to 0^+$:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$and general form is $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (ax)}{x} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: It's not a problem here, but $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}~dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is only true if $a>0$.

Comment: It is not completely satisfactory to resort to arguments like "it is well known that..." and cite an equally sophisticated result, because then it is much shorter to say "it is well known that this integral converges".