# Equality of Integrals When Shifting Bounds By Complex Constant

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-integration

I am trying to determine whether the following is true: Let $f(x)$ be any integrable function satisfying $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) =0$$
Then, for any $k\in \mathbb{C}$, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{\infty + k} f(x) dx$$ Of course, when $k$ is real-valued this is trivial. I'm really just interested in the case where $k$ is purely imaginary. I believe this would follow automatically if I could show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} F(x+k)=L,$$ for all $k \in \mathbb{C}$. The left-hand side limit tells me that for all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|x| > \delta \implies |F(x)-L| < \varepsilon$. At this point I'd like to say that we can swap out our absolute value signs for complex moduli and claim that $|x+k| > \delta \implies |F(x+k)-L| < \varepsilon$, where this is no longer the absolute value, but the complex modulus. While this sort of seems like it should follow, I can't rigorously justify claiming that something being true under the absolute value with real-valued entries implies that it's also true under the complex modulus and complex-valued entries. After all, we know that $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$, but $|\sin(z)|$ is unbounded.

Comment: I don't know what $\int_{0}^{\infty + k} f(x) dx$ means.  Is $f$ defined for some non-real values?

Comment: I mean $\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{0}^{x+k} f(x) dx$. For example, you see integrals such as $\int_{0}^{\infty - i} f(x) dx$ in the context of contour integration. See the following link for an example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141695/how-to-calculate-the-integral-of-sin2x-x2

Comment: In the link I posted in my above comment, I am referencing robjohn's answer to the posted question. He computes an integral of this form.

Comment: usually, you need an analytic $F$ and then use Cauchy to pass between line integrals (note that this entails bunch of things like no non-zero residues in-between, the integrals on horizontal lines are zero or converge to zero etc) - note the Gaussian integral for example shifts as you wish only when you integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ but not from $0$ to $\infty$ and I can easily concoct examples with poles in-between etc