# Computing the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}dx$ via complex analysis

Tags: improper-integrals, complex-integration

One question in a complex analysis test from the past asks to find the real integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}dx$$
Of course this should be done by contour integration, by I can't figure out how.

What I have so far in my hand:

- Trying to integrate $\frac{1-\cos z}{z^2}$ on an arc (part of a circle) doesn't seem to yield a nice expression.
- Note that this function has a removable singularity at $0$ so it's analytic in $\mathbb{C}$. I can also find the Taylor series but I don't think that's the way.
- This integral equals (by trig identities) $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin^2u}{u^2}du$ but I don't know if it contirbutes in any way.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should use the Jordan's lemma

Comment: @DF How, may I ask?

Comment: See [Can I solve this using Complex integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992534/can-i-solve-this-using-complex-integration) or [Integral by residue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371194/integral-by-residue) or [How to integrate this improper integral.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970612/how-to-integrate-this-improper-integral/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Using an integration by part, one can remark that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx.$$

Consider $$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$$
on
$$D=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid \varepsilon<|z|<R, \Im(z)\geq 0\}.$$

Answer (score -1):

$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1-cosx}{x^2} = \int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{sin(\alpha x)}{x}d\alpha dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{sin(\alpha x)}{x}dxd\alpha = \int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{2}d \alpha = \pi /2$

Comment: While correct, this method does not use tools from complex analysis.

Comment: As it's written : using COMPLEX analysis

Comment: @Surb You have to use complex analysis in order to compute the Dirichlet integral $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{sin(ax)}{x}dx$ but such integral can easily be found  in Google.

Comment: You anyway don't answer the question ! (-1)