# Alternate Integral Representation of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin ((k+1)x)\sin (kx)}{(xk^2)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I am looking for alternate integral representation of

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin ((k+1)x)\sin (kx)}{x^2k^4}dx \tag{1}\label{1}$$

After trying this for some time it doesn't seem like it has a nice integral representation. I'm least interested in evaluating the integral, I'm wondering if $\eqref{1}$ can be written in a nice integral form.

Any help or hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be. The reference will help :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106570/how-do-i-show-that-int-infty-infty-frac-sin-x-sin-nxx2-dx-pi

Comment: The solution in the post is given for arbitrary $a>b>0$: $2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)\sin(bx)}{x^2}\;dx=\pi b$

Comment: I'm looking for an alternate representation not a simplified version of it